# Android startActivity() crashing

Tags: android, android-intent

Basic disclaimer; I am new to mobile app programming in general, and android in particular.

I have a button that, when clicked, should open the next activity:

```
bCustom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DiceCustomList.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

(where "private Context ctx = this;" because putting "this" where "ctx" is did not get the context when inside onClick)

The program crashes before the current activity is obscured (though I'm not sure how transitions affect this). After commenting out nearly everything, here's the activity it's calling:

```
public class DiceCustomList extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_list);
    }
}
```

And custom_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="@string/rollText"
        android:id="@+id/textRoll2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="11pt"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I think the problem lies in the button code, but I can't seem to get closer to the answer than that.

Edit: The android manifest file does have:

```
<activity android:name=".DiceCustomList"></activity>
```

Edit 2: Ah, after finally finding where Eclipse hides the stacktrace, it told me this: "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'", by which they actually mean "@+id/android:list". Well, that was interesting. (Edit3: By which I mean, it was the answer. Thanks for the prompting.)

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error.

Comment: Logcat is your best friend for debugging Android apps.  adb is located in the 'Platform Tools' directory of your SDK.  Run it from the console as `adb logcat`.  You can view Logcat messages from inside Eclipse, but I find it clutters things too much and is easier to run separately.

Answer (score 9):

Check to make sure the DiceCustomList activity has an  entry in the manifest XML file.

Comment: It does. Is this enough? <activity android:name=".DiceCustomList"></activity>

Comment: This is likely the issue. In addition you can use EnclosingClass.this rather than ctx in the onclick listener and you should post the stacktrace of any crashes in the future so people will be more likely to have enough information to help.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how to get Eclipse to actually output the particular error. Android says it crashed, and that's all the info I get.

Answer (score 1):

> (where "private Context ctx = this;"
>   because putting "this" where "ctx" is
>   did not get the context when inside
>   onClick)

You may use YourActivity.this to get the context. Simple 'this' does not work because inside this method it points to OnClickListener object.

Can you please give us a LogCat error logs?

Comment: Took me a bit, Eclipse hides the stacktrace well (I'm not used to Eclipse. It has everything, but that means it has to find a place to put it, and "LogCat" is not exactly an intuitive name). Thanks for the prompting. Edit2 on the main post shows the answer I found.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `DiceCustomList` class is extending `ListActivity` but the layout file is missing some required pieces.

The layout file for a `ListActivity` must have the following 2 elements with specific IDs.  The `ListActivity` class uses these elements to bind a data adapter to the list in your activity (using `setListAdapter(myAdapter);` );

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
           {other attributes ommitted} />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
           {other attributes ommitted} />
```

The Android docs have good reference XML and example of binding a cursor:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

In general though, you should get familiar with `adb` and `logcat`.  Due to the way the emulator debugs apps, many times your app will crash and you'll just see a "Source not found" message in Eclipse.  Wrapping problem code in try/catch blocks and logging the exceptions ( `Log.e( TAG, MESSAGE);` ) is a quick & easy way to see what's really going on.